# How can I override a module's file via hook_menu_alter()?

Tags: routes

I have the following code in my hook_menu_alter().

```
<?php

function bonus_menu_alter(&$items) {

  if (!empty($items['things'])){

    $items['things']['title'] = t("New title");
    $items['things']['callback'] = 'new_callback';
    $items['things']['file path'] = drupal_get_path("module", "bonus")."/includes/";
    $items['things']['file'] = 'bonus.pages.inc';

  }

}
```

The problem is that the file path of the new file is including the original modules path and spitting this out:

```
/var/www/staging/sites/all/modules/things/sites/all/modules/bonus/includes/bonus.pages.inc
```

The original implementation of the parent hook_menu():

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function things_menu() {
  $items['things'] = array(
    'title' => 'Things title',
    'page callback' => 'things_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'includes/things.pages.inc',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Silly me, always make sure "page callback" is called that and not "callback" like i had done :)

Comment: "page callback" happened to be a side issue. Not the answer to the actual issue in this question. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 8):

I think this happens because your alter hook does not update the value for `$items['bonus']['module']`, which was automatically set to 'things' when [menu_router_build](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7) processed `things_menu()`. Try this:

```
$items['bonus']['module'] = 'bonus';
$items['bonus']['file path'] = '/includes/';
$items['bonus']['file'] = 'bonus.pages.inc';
```

or simply this, more like the things module does:

```
$items['bonus']['module'] = 'bonus';
$items['bonus']['file'] = 'includes/bonus.pages.inc';
```